# Does XSLT schema aware validation work with "alternative"

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xsd-1.1

(This is a completely rewritten question)

I'm using Saxon C# API saxon9ee-api library to "compile" (for the purposes of validation) schema aware xslts against their schema (I was using Oxygen, but actually that adds a layer of configuration that makes things more complex).
The objective is to formalise a "style" of XSD (which will be autogenerated) and a "style" of XSLT (which will be written by humans) that catches as many errors in the XSLT should the XSD change.

lets take an xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:complexType name="TRIANGLETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE">
    <!--<xs:alternative type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>-->
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and take an XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxsl"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:import-schema schema-location="MessingAbout.xsd"/>
  <xsl:template match="schema-element(TRIANGLE)">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="@rotation"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this will behave nicely...this one validates, if I change the "rotation" reference to "rotation1" then I get

```
The complex type Q{}TRIANGLETYPE does not allow an attribute named rotation1
```

Which is what I want.
But if I change the XSD to say

```
  <xs:element name="TRIANGLE">
    <xs:alternative type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
  </xs:element>
```

instead of the explicit type

```
  <xs:element name="TRIANGLE" type="TRIANGLETYPE">
```

then the inference on the XSLT "fails" - in the sense that it will not detect the type fault in the XSLT when it refers to the attribute "rotation1", which is not defined.

So the questions are

- Does "alternative" basically short circuit the type checking? (even if there is only 1 alternative - do I understand the semantics of alternative?)
- If so is there a way around this (i.e. its been suggested to use "element()" which I'll try.
- additionally, is there some options to raise warnings for sections of code that cannot/has not been type checked, I'd like to exclude the false positive scenario by detecting this as a warning.

an additional question, is there any good tutorials/books etc on schema aware XSLTs, short of trying to comprehend the specification, there is pitifully little out there.

Comment: You can use `element(FOO_ELEMENT, FooType)` I think to "match in a template based on element name AND a type". Whether that solves your problem I am not sure.

Comment: When you say you are "doing a validation", are you actually talking about static type inference in the XSLT processor? Generally it's true that there's no guarantee that all type errors will be detected statically. If this isn't what you mean, please try to explain more clearly exactly what you are doing, and how the results differ from expectations. A *reproducible example* is always useful.

Comment: I'll put a complete example in tomorrow. I think I'm happy with a non guarenteed type check as long as I know where the holes are.

Comment: So for the question you don't have any XML input you are trying to process and validate, you are just asking about the warning you get when compiling the XSLT and the use of attributes like `@rotation1` in XPath expressions inside a schema matched element?

Comment: yes...this is just about compiling (obviously I want the XSLT to do something sensible when executed, but thats a secondary issue, this is just about generating a 'descriptive' schema, and then using that to exploit type information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only tested with Saxon 10 EE but there indeed `xsl:template match="element(TRIANGLE, TRIANGLETYPE)"` seems a way to trigger the warning of e.g. "SXWN9000  The complex type Q{}TRIANGLETYPE does not allow an attribute named rotation1".

Comment: does that mean that execution that the "test" clauses of "alternatives" are evaluated in order for the type to be evaluated, and then the templated to be able to match the types in the element function?

Comment: thats worked, I'll mark it as the answer soon, any idea if we can force saxon to report unchecked code as a warning?